# How do I get my variable to show in my store function

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is probably a very simple thing, but for some reason I just can't figure it out. I created a function that gets the images from my vue component. 
What I'm trying to do is take the images from my postImage() and have them in my store() function, so that I can save everything into the database. 
The problem I'm getting is when I do that I get this error

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\CategoryController::store(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

I do understand that the error is telling me that only the `$request` was sent and not the `$image`. I'm not sure how to get it working. If I've left anything out please let me know

Here is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request, $image)
{

    $category = new Category();

    $input = $this->safeInput($request);

    $category->fill($input);

    dd($image);

    $slug = $category->slug($category->title);
    $category->slug = $slug;

    if($request->has('active'))
    {
        $category->active = 1;
    }else{
        $category->active = 0;
    }

    $category_order = $category->order_number();
    $category->order = $category_order;

    $category->save();
}

public function postImage(Request $request)
{

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $names = [];
        foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
        {
            $destinationPath = 'product_images/category/';
            $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            array_push($names, $filename);          
        }

        $image = json_encode($names);
        return $image;
    }
}
```

This is my vue component

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="uploader"
            @dragenter="OnDragEnter"
            @dragleave="OnDragLeave"
            @dragover.prevent
            @drop="onDrop"

        >

            <div v-show="!images.length" :value="testing()">
                <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                <div>OR</div>
                <div class="file-input">
                    <label for="file">Select a file</label>
                    <input type="file" id="file" @change="onInputChange" multiple>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="images-preview" v-show="images.length">
                <div class="img-wrapper" v-for="(image, index) in images">
                    <img :src="image" :alt="`Image Uplaoder ${index}`">

                    <div class="details">
                        <span class="name" v-text="files[index].name"></span>
                        <span class="size" v-text="getFileSize(files[index].size)"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="btn btn-danger" @click="funDeleteFile(index)">
                        Remove
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        data() {
            return {
                isDragging: false,
                //Sets the dragCount to 0
                dragCount: 0,
                //Makes files an array, so that we can send the files to the server
                files: [],
                //Makes images an array, so that we can let the user see the images
                images: [],
            }
        },

        methods: {
            testing() {
                console.log('This is submit images - '+this.files);

                var formData = new FormData();
                this.files.forEach(file => {
                    formData.append('image[]', file, file.name);
                }); 

                axios.post('/admin/category/post-image', formData);
            },

            OnDragEnter(e) {
                //Prevents the default action of the browser
                e.preventDefault();

                // This lets the dragCount become 1, so that the image uploader changes colour
                this.dragCount++;

                // Changes the isDragging variable to true instead of false
                this.isDragging = true;

                return false;
            },

            OnDragLeave(e) {
                //Prevents the default action of the browser
                e.preventDefault();

                // This lets the dragcount become 0, so that the image uploader changes to it's original colour
                this.dragCount--;

                // This is if the dragCount is <= 0 then the isDragging variable is false
                if (this.dragCount <= 0)
                    this.isDragging = false;
            },

            onInputChange(e) {
                // Grabs the files from the event
                const files = e.target.files;

                // Creates an array for files, so that we can loop thru it
                // Send the file to the addImage method via "this.addImage(file)"
                Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));
            },

            onDrop(e) {
                //Prevents the default action of the browser
                e.preventDefault();

                //Stops the propagation into the other elements inside the one we drop and file into
                e.stopPropagation();

                // This is to disable the dragging of the images
                this.isDragging = false;

                // Grabs the files from the event
                const files = e.dataTransfer.files;

                // Creates an array for files, so that we can loop thru it
                // Send the file to the addImage method via "this.addImage(file)"
                Array.from(files).forEach(file => this.addImage(file));
            },

            addImage(file) {
                //Checks if the file type is an image
                if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                    this.$toastr.e(`${file.name} is not an image`);
                    return;
                }

                this.files.push(file);

                const img = new Image(),

                reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = (e) => this.images.push(e.target.result);
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);



            },


        }
    }
</script>
```

my create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
    @component('admin.components.products.category-form', [
                'formUrl' => route('category.store'),
                'formMethod' => 'POST',
                'model' => $category,
                'category_id' => $category_id,
                'image' => '',
                'image2' => ''
            ])
    @endcomponent
@endsection
```

and my form

```
{{ Form::model($model, array('url' => $formUrl, 'method' => $formMethod, 'class' => 'add-form', 'files' => true)) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Parent Category') }}
        {{ Form::select('category_id', $category_id->prepend('Please Select', '0'), null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('title', 'Title') }}
        {{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Active:</label>
        {{ Form::checkbox('active', 0) }}
    </div>

    <div id="app" class="mb-20">
        <category-image></category-image>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => "btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block")) }}
    </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

My routes

```
Route::resource('admin/category', 'Admin\CategoryController');
Route::post('admin/category/post-image', 'Admin\CategoryController@postImage')->name('admin.category.post-image');
```

UPDATE

I've tried this to pass the image to a hidden field in my form so that I can grab it in the $request in my store function.

In my CategoryController@create

```
$category = new Category();

$category_list = Category::with('parentCategory')->get();
$category_id = Category::pluck('title', 'id');
// I've added this.
$image = '';

return view('admin.products.category.create', compact('category', 'category_list', 'category_id', 'image'));
```

in my CategoryController@postImage

```
//I've added this to, so that I can pass the image variable to the create.blade.php
return redirect()->route('category.create', compact('image'));
```

then in my create.blade.php I added

```
'my_image' => $my_image
```

and in my category-form.blade.php component I added

```
<div id="app" class="mb-20">
    <category-image></category-image>
    <input type="hidden" name="image" id="image" value="{{ $my_image }}">
</div>
```

at the moment I haven't been able to do that either. Though I'm not sure if this is the right way to go, I'm a bit worried that some random person can then add whatever they want by using the hidden input

Comment: Remove ```$image``` from ```store``` method. I dont think so you are using it in ```store``` method anywhere

Comment: From where you're passing `$image` to `store` func? The error says that you're not passing 2nd parameter to store func which is `$image`

Comment: not clear what you want to do describe question well

Answer (score 0):

For what do you have the parameter $image? This is not specified in your axios.post.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $category = new Category();

    $input = $this->safeInput($request);

    $category->fill($input);

    dd($this->postImage($request));

    $slug = $category->slug($category->title);
    $category->slug = $slug;

    if($request->has('active'))
    {
        $category->active = 1;
    }else{
        $category->active = 0;
    }

    $category_order = $category->order_number();
    $category->order = $category_order;

    $category->save();
}

public function postImage($request)
{

    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $names = [];
        foreach($request->file('image') as $image)
        {
            $destinationPath = 'product_images/category/';
            $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            array_push($names, $filename);          
        }

        $image = json_encode($names);
        return $image;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that the `FormData` passes the image

Comment: also `dd($this->postImage($request));` passes a null

Answer (score 0):

In your create.blade you use 'formUrl' => route('category.store'), this route calls the "store" method, right? If so, it also needs to pass the $image parameter. It would be easier to identify the problem if we could se your web routes file too.

If route('category.store') does call the store method you have a few options.

1 - If you don't really need the $image parameter for the store method, you could just remove it.

2 - If you need it in a few cases, just make the parameter optional and check if it's received before handling it. Example: store(Request $request, $image = null)

3 - If this parameter actually is required, you will have to pass it everytime, even when calling routes. Example: route('category.store', ['image' => $something]). Looking at your code at this moment in create.blade you don't have the content to pass though, so I don't think this is an option.

Comment: I've added my routes to my question.

Comment: I do need my image to be passed because it is required. I have thought of trying to pass my `$image` to my blade after I dragged it to the image component, but I haven't managed to do that. I've updated my question to say what I've tried

Comment: I've sent another answer based on your new information.

Answer (score 0):

If the $request is available there, Then there  is no need to pass extra $image variable.
have you tried

```
dd($request)
```

or 
`print_r($request->toArray()); exit;`
for see what's in your request!

Comment: When I do that I only get the category_id and title

Comment: set name to `[input type="file"]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the image missing in the request object sent through the form, it is the second parameter required by the category.store method.

Even if you now send the image in the form with a hidden field, you would still need to pass it as a parameter everytime you call the category.store.

Your store method is defined like

```
store(Request $request, $image)
```

So, when you call this method, even if you're just getting the route URL with route('category.store'), you do need to send the image parameter in this call.
Example:

```
route('category.store', ['image' => 'image id here']);
```

The same goes for the route definition in your web routes file. You're using a resource route, but laravel don't expect a second parameter for the store method in a default resource, so you will need to change that.

```
/*
adds exception to the resource so it will not handle the store method
*/
Route::resource('admin/category', 'Admin\CategoryController')->except(['store']);

//adds a custom route that supports the $image parameter.
Route::post('admin/category/{image}', 'Admin\CategoryController@store')
```

---

Now, if you're planning to send the image through the request object, you don't need it as a second parameter, so the only thing you will need to change is to make your category.store method like that.

```
public function store(Request $request)
```

Comment: If I do `public function store(Request $request)` then how do I go about getting the images to save along with the rest of the form? Since the images is a vue component, and from my understanding (in my case) there isn't a way to grab the images and add it to the $request